EF Core Adding Unwanted Default Value to String Property
I'm encountering an issue with Entity Framework Core (using Pomelo for MySQL) in my .NET Core 6 application. When I update or recreate the database, a specific field (OperationCode) in my XXX table is automatically assigned a default value of a single double-quote ("). This property is not null, and I've used the same code for some other fields in another table, where it is working fine.
Model
public string Tag { get; set; } = null!;
Context
`
              entity.Property(e => e.Tag)
               .HasColumnType("varchar(250)")
               .HasColumnName("tag"); `

Column

Why is the OperationCode field in the XXX table being set to a default value of a single double-quote ("), and how can I prevent this from happening?
Any insights or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

string Tag means the property is not nullable. If you want to store nulls in that field change the type to string?

I don't want to store a null value. I have used the same code for other tables. When I inspect those tables, it doesn’t show a single double-quote (").but i can manually remove it using ALTER TABLE. However, when I delete the database and recreate it, that default value, which I never set in my code, appears again. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Is it a single double quote or two single quotes? You've  declared the property as a non-null-able string so EF code-first is likely going to set up an initial default value of an empty string. (two single quotes)  Though if it is getting set to a double-quote that would seem to be a bit of a bug or some rogue configuration elsewhere.

default value should be coded in sql design, a single double-quote shall not pass, check what exactly it is. Considered your issue occurs in certain file but acts as expected in others, It might not be .net core issue, you could check the migration file to get details.
